# preg_split : Get first word in a line

Tags: php, regex, preg-split

Can you please help assemble a regex to be used in `preg_split` which will split a string on it's first word - case insensitive (up until the first space).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work

```
$result = preg_split('/\s/', trim($subject));
$firstword = $result[0]
```

Comment: With the addition of 2 to third param, so it would only match first word, it worked great. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If sentence has space as word separators you can do:

```
list($firstWord) = explode(' ',trim($input));
```

Answer (score 0):

If you just need to split up until the first space character, your regex is essentially just a space character:

```
$output = preg_split('/ /', 'My name is Mansoor', 2);
echo $output[0]; // Will return 'My';
echo $output[1]; // will return 'name is Mansoor';
```

If you only need the first word, make sure you pass the optional argument (the `2`) to specify that you want only two results in your `$output` array -- the first word, and the rest of the sentence.  Otherwise, you'll spend time parsing text that you don't care about.

Comment: Didn't work. Result:       $line = 'Name John Doe';
$line_parts = preg_split('(/ /)', $line, 2);
// Array ( [0] => Name John Doe )

Comment: Apologies, the round brackets shouldn't have been in the expression.  Corrected.

Comment: It has to be **preg_split** because is a function not variable.